# Accept user input and set assign to variable PL/SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to accept user input inside of a stored procedure and assign it to a VARCHAR variable. For some reason I get error

> PLS-00201: identifier 'userinput' must be declared.

Any ideas? I have to use this later down the line to see how many times the input appears in a table.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE nums
    AS
       x_num VARCHAR(20);
    BEGIN
       x_num := &input;
       dbms_output.put_line('You entered: ' || x_num);
    END;
    /
```

Comment: There is no identifier `userinput` in this example.  Is the error saying `input`?  Or is it `&userinput` in the actual code?

Comment: userinput actually came from the pop up box that prompts me for input whenI ran the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making the input a parameter.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE nums (pInput IN VARCHAR2)
    AS
       x_num VARCHAR(20);
    BEGIN
       x_num := pInput ;
       dbms_output.put_line('You entered: ' || x_num);
    END;
    /
```

Comment: input, in this case, has to come from prompted user input rather than being passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Procedures cannot receive user input in response to a prompt, PLSQL is NOT interactive. When you have that you are not actually communicating with the database. What is actually happening is symbol substitution were SQLPLUS or other interface (Toad , SQL Developer, ...) is actually intercepting symbol, requesting the input, and physically changing the script before submitting it to the database. If you want a stored procedure you will need to use a parameter as @HereGoes suggested and then provide the user a script as follows:

```
Begin 
    nums(pInput => &Input);
end ;
```

Or provide an application interface to receive the input value and call the procedure or allow user access through SQLPLUS or other interface and let them enter the script - not recommended.